# Apache Axis WSDL to Java conversion

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I have a integer field in a class which I have made private and no setter method is provided but when I generate the client with WSDL2Java, the generated class has a setter method.

Why is it so?

I am using Apache Axis 2.

I am putting the code for more explanation

```
public class MyClass {
  private int id;
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

So what should I do to hide the setter method when client is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you creating a web service using a POJO it generates a wsdl file.

What WSDL2java tool uses is that generated wsdl file. But that does not have any idea of the original POJO you use to generate the wsdl. Currently there is no way in Axis2 to generate only the getter methods of the bean classes.

Comment: So @Amila Suriarachchi is there any other way to hide the setter method as I do not want the use the setter method. And also can you please provide me link or resource which explains WSDL2JAVA conversion. I am new to Web Service and WSDL2JAVA appears almost like a black box to me.

Comment: here are some of the links about axis2 wsdl2java tool. [1]http://wso2.org/library/2873 
[2]http://wso2.org/library/2935
[3]http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/reference-guide-axis2-code-generation-parameters-part-1
[4]http://wso2.org/library/2068